# change column names after refreshing JTable java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, jtableheader

I dont know why column names are named "A","B","C" ... after refreshing JTable.

I created a class to refresh JTable.

```
public class TableModelClass extends AbstractTableModel
{
    Object[][] data;
    Object[] title;

public TableModelClass(Object[][] dat, Object[] tit)
{
    data = dat;
    title = tit;    
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount()
{
    if(title != null)
        return title.length;
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount()
{
    if(data != null)
        return data.length;
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}
```

}

I set JTables values default in my class:

```
Object[] titlesDefault = { "tit1", "tit12","tit3"};
Object[][] dataDefault = {{ "1", "2","3"},
            {"1", "2","3"}};


       _jTable = new JTable(dataDefault, titlesDefault);    

_bAddTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
                try
                {
                Object[] titles2 = { "1", "2","3", "1", "2","3"};
                Object[][] data = {{ "1", "2","3"},
                                   { "1", "2","3"},
                       {"1", "2","3"}};
                data.setModel(new TableModelClass(data, titles2));
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException)
                {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }               

         };
        });
```

And after this I receive letters in column names. Why?

Comment: 1) does that code compile? Your Object[][] variable is not a 2-D array but rather a 1-D array of String. 2) Never use a MouseListener on a JButton when an ActionListener is called for.

Comment: code compiles, so what should I use?

Comment: 1) Your 2-D array should hold a 2-D array. 2) Again, JButtons should use ActionListeners. The tutorial will explain all. I'm no JTable pro, but you may need to use a column model as well.

Comment: I tried to use ActionListener but result was the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without overriding `getColumnName`, the `TableModel` uses default values of "A", "B", "C", etc.

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return title[column];
}
```

For this to work you need to return a `String` so that it corresponds to the return type in the super class. The `title` variable should be defined as a `String[]` type.